# SwiftUI update List dynamically

Tags: list, swiftui

I am having issues updating a simple list in SwiftUI :

I've simplified my problem down to the bare minimum.

My environment is XCode 12.4 on MacOS Catalina (10.15.7)
Swift version 5.3.2

After running the following code I would expect to see 3 items in my List yet I get only 2 ("one", "two") :

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyListItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var value: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var itemList: [MyListItem] = [MyListItem(value: "one"),MyListItem(value: "two")]

    var body: some View {
        List(itemList, id: \.id) { item in
            Text(item.value)
        }
    }

    init() {
        print("Init started")
        itemList.append(MyListItem(value: "three"))
        print("Init ended")
    }
}
```

I do get the "Init ended" string in the logs so I know the init script ran.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `.onAppear()`, like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyListItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var value: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var itemList: [MyListItem] = [MyListItem(value: "one"), MyListItem(value: "two")]

    var body: some View {
        List(itemList) { item in
            Text(item.value)
        }
        .onAppear {
            itemList.append(MyListItem(value: "three"))
        }
    }
}
```

You should do your view setup in `init()`, because the life cycle of SwiftUI views is unpredictable by design.

---

TIP:
It is unneccessary to use the `List` initializer with an id: keypath when your object conforms to `Identifiable`.